# How to get the top URL from a Facebook application?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, iframe

How can I get the top URL (Facebook's address) in my iframe application?

Is there a good solution on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean a URL on Facebook's domain?

That's not going to be possible due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: I just mean, how i can get the url from that page the iframe is on.
if you understand ;-)

Comment: @Simon you mean the iframe's URL or the URL of the page that contains the iframe?

Comment: @Pekka the URL of the page that contains the iframe :)

Comment: Same Origin Policy still applies.

Comment: @Simon sorry, not possible. You won't get any information from the parent frame. The URL *would* be in the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` header though - at least in most clients - that you can fetch and output in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can probably figure this out from the "signed_request" POST parameter that Facebook sends to apps loaded within pages.

In PHP that's:

```
$_POST["signed_request"]
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
$page_id = $data["page"]["id"];
```

If you want to prevent technical users from being able to spoof the parent page's identity, you can validate the $encoded_sig; this is probably overkill, however.

The $page_id is just a number, so you'll need to use other Facebook APIs (or make a call to "http://www.facebook.com/pages/k/$page_id" and see where you're redirected to) to get the full URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/YOUR_PAGE_NAME/YOUR_PAGE_ID?sk=app_APP_ID&app_data=My%20custom%20data
```

you can pass any string data by app_data parameter

Answer (score -1):

If you can wait for first load, you can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var myurl = window.location.pathname;
    $.get("test.php", { url: myurl } );
});
```