# How to get facebook app URL based on app ID and page ID

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-apps

Is there any way to get app's URL based on app ID and page ID?
There can be several variants of URL:

> www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_153692631322774
>
> www.facebook.com/pages/Charity-donation/173465756069467?sk=app_261454963888439

I have found something helpful in answer for [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107451/how-to-get-the-top-url-from-a-facebook-application)  - make call to http://www.facebook.com/pages/k/PAGE_ID?v=app_APP_ID .
But this does not works for HTTPS (I am redirected to HTTP).

(Sure, I can make several redirections, but it is too long.)

Comment: does the answer of this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585234/find-out-page-tab-url-from-page-id-and-application-id