# Get root page url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-as3-api

i am developing facebook application, and i need to get the facebook root page url not iframe, all these methods: `document.location`,`window.location` and `top.location`... return the iframe url ( my hosting server ) not facebook url.

any suggestions ?

Comment: I would think that this is a security feature, and that you can't get the URL.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107451/how-to-get-the-top-url-from-a-facebook-application

Answer (score 0):

Try `parent.location.href`. It might not work if the iframe isn't coming from the same domain, and if so you will just need to get the request url referrer with your server code.

Edit: To get the current url in PHP try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: didn't work. application host in domain and of course facebook not in same domain. do you have any idea how to get it using php ?

Comment: Thank you :)  and here is how to load php vars into flash as3 for reference: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=1008997&postcount=6

Comment: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] also get current iframe not parent page ( facebook url ) :S

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, not `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot... its concatenate the facebook query strings to the iframe url `https://iframe_url?request_ids=196452310440879%2C184625744965192&ref=notif¬if_t=app_request` Thank you again